# Magento store view changes after adding an item to the cart

Tags: php, magento, joomla

I have a Joomla / Magento / Magebridge store with a product here:

http://www.slightlyusedlighting.com/shop/new/elation-volt-q5-rgbw-led.html

I have debugging turned on. Right now, the store view is "Magento store loaded: Slightly Used Lighting (sul)" but as you add the item to your cart, the store view changes to "Magento store loaded: Default Store View (default)."

How do I prevent the store view from changing, permanently?

I've already tried this code in index.php:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'sul';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

$mageRunCode = 'sul';
$mageRunType = 'website';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```